Replacing a GUID with a new one in a file [Linux]
I'm trying to make a script that will change a guid string within a file. So pretty much a little something along the lines of i need it to search within a file and within quotations and replace a guid from within those quotations. So far I got this:
#!/bin/bash
grep -w MachineGuid /home/admin/VMList/pc3.ID >/tmp/old.ID
# (that makes a file in tmp with  and contains example GUID
# "MachineGuid"="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx") 
uuidgen >/tmp/new.ID
# (this makes another file called new.ID but it only contains
# xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx and is missing the
# "MachineGuid"=" part)old.IDnew.ID

I need to find a way to only replace the numbers within the machine guid with the new generated numbers stored in "pc3.ID"
In summary to look in "pc3.ID " file and find the MachineGuid"="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
and ONLY replace it x's with a new GUID that was generated from uuidgen that stored it in a file and make it MachineGuid="yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy".
Or if there's an easier way let me know.
I'm trying to learn sed but it's a little rough.
I've been trying numerous amount of sed commands that I'm trying to learn but it has a really been working out in my favor. I'm trying to find a way to replace the machine id that was generated with uuidgen and update it within the new id file.

"I've been trying numerous amount of sed commands that I'm trying to learn but it has a really been working out in my favor." - Please show us your attempts.

using linux without sed , grep  & awk is like just having a book and  never opening it . you know what that books is related but you dont know what it contains.

send me you list i will give it a shot

Easier is a matter of opinion.  If you were (say) proficient Python and knew no Sed, then Python would be easier.

Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable, textual (no links, no images) sample input and expected output that demonstrates your needs and we can copy/paste to test with. See [ask] and look at existing questions that have been upvoted and answered for examples.

My take would be a sed only solution:
sed -i -e '/MachineGuid/s/MachineGuid="[^"]*"/MachineGuid="'$(uuidgen)'"/' pc3.ID

This inline-replaces (-i) all lines matching MachineGuid and with an assignment in quotes with a newly generated GUID.
Note that you don't need to know the old GUID. The "[^"]*" part matches a double quote followed by zero or more non-double quotes, followed by a quote. It is instructive to familiarize yourself with the power of basic and extended regular expressions, also abbreviated as BRE and ERE.

You should mention that requires GNU sed for that use of -i.

@EdMorton Well, FreeBSD sed was the one I used, but since the question is tagged Linux, I assumed GNU sed is available to the OP. Advice for the OP: many Unix utilities that take options may work differently or not be available once you change your OS (or even Linux distro). If you strive for portability of your scripts, it is essential to know what the POSIX Standard says you can expect. The 24 Edition was just released: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9799919799/index.html

Though it would produce the desired output, FreeBSD sed would have consumed the e after -i as the extension to use for backups, not as a separate -e argument which I think is what you intended it to be as -e is a common sed argument while e would be an odd choice for a backup extension. Actually, I guess GNU sed would have treated e as the extension too so I suppose it just looks odd (maybe just to me).

@Jens this command didn't work but i executed the command while i had to file open with kate file manager and it says a change has occurred but then when i view it it says files are identical and no change was made to the machine id.

@XDMInc I have split the options -i and -e now and tested it under Ubuntu Linux to work. Does it work now for you?

I had already tried that and it didn't work but also omitted the e as according to the manual that's just to make a backup and it also didn't work. I don't know why but it just modifies the file but doesn't change anything My file browser says it's been modified but it's not doing anything.

i just ended up mixing some of what i have been reading here with a little quick and dirty solution
#!/bin/sh

#command to take note of existing MachineGuid and places them in tmp
cat ~/VMList/pc3.ID | grep -w MachineGuid >/tmp/raw.ID
#remove characters but the UUID
cut -c 16-51 /tmp/raw.ID >/tmp/old.ID
#read from the ID files in tmp,use cat to tell sed what it needs to find,then execute uuidgen and write to file specified
sed -i s/$(cat /tmp/old.ID)/$(uuidgen)/ ~/VMList/pc3.ID
#cleanup
rm /tmp/raw.ID /tmp/old.ID

this does the trick!

There's a useless use of cat. grep can take the file name pc3.ID as an argument.

I just needed something to work for now to get me through my work sessions. I might try to refine it next week. But honestly even with the useless cat right now it just works  flawlessly and I'm afraid to touch it.
